# Updating multiple rows in MySQL without a loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm trying to write up an email notification system for a job recruitment site I made and am currently looking at grouping a certain amount of jobs together before sending an email to the candidate

I have a table which I've called candidate_to_job which contains the candidate_id, job_id and an "emailed" boolean

What I'm struggling with is updating that table when a new job is posted and emails are sent out. So far when a new job is posted I run the following:

```
SELECT     c2j.candidate_id, c2j.job_id, j.title 
FROM       " . DB_PREFIX . "candidate_to_job c2j 
LEFT JOIN  " . DB_PREFIX . "job j 
       ON  (j.job_id = c2j.job_id) 
WHERE      c2j.emailed = 0
```

Then through PHP I group them all together so I have an array looking something like this:

```
$candidates = array(
    1 => array(1,2,3),
    2 => array(1,3),
    3 => array(4,5,6)
);
```

With the array key being the candidate ID and the value an array of job IDs

What I want to do using that array - after the emails have been sent - is update the candidate_to_job table setting emailed to true, e.g candidate_id 1 would have emailed set to true for job_ids 1, 2 and 3

Is there a way I can do this in one query? I've looked at WHEN CASE statements but I don't think that applies in this case? I really don't want to run multiple queries per candidate because there could potentially be thousands!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run one `UPDATE` query per group provided that the group can share the same `WHERE` criteria and the same update values.

```
UPDATE tbl SET value = TRUE WHERE id IN(1,2,3,4,5,6);
UPDATE tbl SET value = FALSE WHERE id IN(7,8,9,10,11);
```

Or you can use the `WHEN` clause or even some `IF` clauses provided that the criteria are simple enough.

```
UPDATE tbl SET value = IF(id = 1) WHERE id IN(1,2);
UPDATE tbl
    SET value = CASE
                    WHEN id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) THEN TRUE
                    WHEN id IN (7,8,9,10,11) THEN FALSE
                    ELSE value
                END
    WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);
```

Having possibly thousands of `WHEN` cases, may be a hassle to build/change, I'd go with the first option:

Flip the old key=>value array and keep all ids connected to a value:

```
foreach($list AS $id => $value) {
    $list2[$value][] = $id;
}
```

Iterate through the value=>keys array and build `UPDATE` queries that can bulk update the value for all keys at once.

Comment: I never even thought of flipping the array around. That's a good idea, I can make another array with the key as the job id then the value an array of candidate_ids - thanks!

Comment: @ypercube Thank you, i never thought of using `IN` with a `CASE`, SQL syntax is less intuitive as to what exactly is a fixed flow-control-construct vs. predefined functions vs. statement-syntax, etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mysqli extension in PHP instead of mysql, you can also write mutliple statements seperated by ';' and send all of them in one query. This might result in slightly simpler code than a complex UPDATE with cases.

I dont think this costs much more performance than one single complex UPDATE statement.

Comment: As a rule of thumb i always "compact" multiple statements that I can run at once because the communication protocol between PHP and MySQL works over TCP (it is usually a local DB but it's still TCP) and limiting those TCP communications is just as good an idea as limiting disk IO or any other expensive resource.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?  You can do a join using from and where without having to dynamically generate SQL in PHP.

```
UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "candidate_to_job c2j 
SET emailed = 1
FROM  " . DB_PREFIX . "job j 
WHERE j.job_id = c2j.job_id and
      c2j.emailed = 0
```

Comment: Isn't that just the same as UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "candidate_to_job SET emailed = 1 WHERE emailed = 0? There doesn't seem to be any criteria on which rows to update

Comment: And implicit filter is applied to any matches on the table job.  If you created your PHP array from the result of your first query then this should work.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood. Every job is in the job table, so the WHERE j.job_id = c2j.job_id is always going to be true isn't it? The entries are added to the candidate_to_job table when a job is posted and it matches the candidates job criteria

Comment: Could you provide some more context as to how this is implemented?  In your question you state that you run the SQL then use PHP to stick the results into an array of arrays.  How are you determining what goes in the array?